# Python - Equality Error

Tags: python

I am having an equality issue. The following code compares the nested lists to the list dice.

```
def largeStraight(dice):
    straightValues = [{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {2, 3, 4, 5, 6}]
    return any(value.issubset(dice) for value in straightValues)

def smallStraight(dice):
    straightValues = [{1, 2, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 4, 5} , {3 ,4, 5, 6}]
    return any(value.issubset(dice) for value in straightValues)

def giveResult(dice):
    score = 0
    if(largeStraight):
        score = 40
    elif(smallStraight):
        score = 30
    else:
        score = 0
    return score

dice = [1,2,3,4,1]
print(giveResult(dice))
```

This should return a value of 30 from giveResult, however I am getting a score of 40.

Comment: First thing you need to do is `largeStraight(dice)` and `smallStraight(dice)`.  You aren't passing dice, but instead are evaluating truthiness of a function, which is True.

Answer (score 3):

You need to **call** your functions:

```
def giveResult(dice):
    score = 0
    if largeStraight(dice):
        score = 40
    elif smallStraight(dice):
        score = 30
    else:
        score = 0
    return score
```

Just referring to a function object means your first `if` will match, as most Python objects are considered true in a boolean context.

You can return early, simplifying your function a little:

```
def giveResult(dice):
    if largeStraight(dice):
        return 40
    if smallStraight(dice):
        return 30
    return 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing anything into your methods:

```
def giveResult(dice):
    score = 0
    if(largeStraight(dice)):
        score = 40
    elif(smallStraight(dice)):
        score = 30
    else:
        score = 0
    return score
```